# Should I cancel my visa if I applied 1.5 hours too early?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

Will my UK visa be rejected if I applied 1.5 hours too early? The student visa application says to apply no more than 3 months in advance. I applied on June 10 in Japan, but that ended up being 1.5 hours too early in the UK (June 9 22:30 instead of June 10 for a Sep 10 course start date). My biometrics appointment is in a week. Should I cancel for a refund and reapply?

Comment: 90 days doesn't mean 3 months, so 90 days before September 10 is June 12, not June 10.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The application specified 3 months so I edited my question. So technically I'm 92 days and 1.5 hours early.

Comment: It's reasonable to want to enter the UK a few days before the course start date so you can unpack and get over jet lag. If you do apply again, consider adjusting your planned arrival date.

Comment: @user16259 Assuming the earliest application date depends on arrival date rather than course start date.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I believe it does, but that doesn't affect the point I wanted to make: the asker appeared to be planning to get off a plane and go direct to course registration. If there are any problems it's easier to deal with them when you're not jet lagged.

Comment: @user16259 The asker doesn't mention when they want to travel: only their course start date.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it is implied by the question. If they intended to arrive on September 5 then the question about applying too early would not arise.

Comment: AFAIK, the application is officially accepted for processing when you’ve submitted your biometrics. So I think you can change your appointment date to within 90 days of your intended travel date ie June 12 or later. You don’t need to cancel and reapply.